# Delta normalization and density of states in the Golden rule of Fermi

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, fermis-golden-rule

In the text-book derivation of first order inelastic scattering amplitude, box normalization is usually used to calculate the result. This leads to a correct result through the Golden Rule of Fermi, but when I read [Quantum Mechanics - A Modern Development by Ballentine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810241054), who avoids the box normalization completely and doesn't even mention Fermi's Golden Rule throughout the scattering theory chapter, I'm having difficulty deriving the usual ratio of momenta in

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\sigma_{if}}{\mathrm{d}\Omega} \propto \frac{k^\prime}{k} |V_{fi}|^2$$

using this approach. The only scattering amplitude that seems near to this is eq. 16.59/16.60 in his book, but those are both quite general expressions (so I would think filling in the correct wave functions here should give me the above).

Any pointers in how to arrive at the above formula without applying box normalization is welcome.